# Timechart graph in Splunk with log data

Tags: graph, splunk

I'm new to Splunk and in the last few days I'm trying to figure out how to create a graph with my log data that will contain some fields with their values and names but I'm failing to figure it out. Is this even possible to have a graph in Splunk like in this screenshot ([graph screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLSK4.png))?

This is my data structure:

```
{"app_name": "my_app_name", "component": "component_name", "process": "input", "count": 150, "version": "2022.01.03.120212", "quality": "quality_name", "type": "type_name", "release": "release_name"}
```

So I need the DATAx to be the "component_name", and count and version to be as they are in the logs.

I tried using timechart but it requires to have some math operation which I don't need and I tried xyseries but either I don't know how to use it or I can't make a query to have all my data in the graph. I'd appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Please share the `timechart` query you tried.  What "math operation" was required?  Understand that `timechart` requires the `_time` field, which may have to be computed.

Comment: I didn't even try to use it as from examples I saw everyone used like "avg, count, max...." but I don't need to calculate anything. I kind of need SELECT component_name, count, version FROM my_logs. that's it? I don't need to calculate anything

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see what you've tried so we don't suggest the same thing.  Perhaps this example query will help.

````
| makeresults | eval data="{\"app_name\": \"my_app_name\", \"component\": \"component_name\", \"process\": \"input\", \"count\": 150, \"version\": \"2022.01.03.120212\", \"quality\": \"quality_name\", \"type\": \"type_name\", \"release\": \"release_name\"}
{\"app_name\": \"my_app_name\", \"component\": \"component_name2\", \"process\": \"input\", \"count\": 140, \"version\": \"2022.01.03.120212\", \"quality\": \"quality_name\", \"type\": \"type_name\", \"release\": \"release_name\"}
{\"app_name\": \"my_app_name\", \"component\": \"component_name\", \"process\": \"input\", \"count\": 130, \"version\": \"2022.01.03.120213\", \"quality\": \"quality_name\", \"type\": \"type_name\", \"release\": \"release_name\"}
{\"app_name\": \"my_app_name\", \"component\": \"component_name2\", \"process\": \"input\", \"count\": 120, \"version\": \"2022.01.03.120213\", \"quality\": \"quality_name\", \"type\": \"type_name\", \"release\": \"release_name\"}" | eval data=split(data,"
") | mvexpand data | eval _raw=data
```Everything above just sets up test data```
```Parse the JSON events```
| spath 
```Put the fields of interest into a form that can be visualized```
| xyseries version component count
````

Once you have results, switch to the Visualization tab to graph it.